# Linux 'screen' will not read from disk

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, gnu-screen

I am running a simple multithreaded producer/consumer framework in Java to do some processing. The framework reads from some files, process the data, and writes some results back to disk.

My problem is the following: Because of (very) high memory footprint on the processing, all processing must be done in batches in the following manner:

1 - Start the framework

2 - Do the processing

3 - Shutdown the framework

which are all in a shell script. To do this I open a screen so the processing can continue even when I am not around, and start the shell script. However, what I experience is that if I disconnect the screen (CTRL-A + D) the framework will complain that it, all of a sudden, cannot find the java byte-compiled classes of the framework. This problem goes away completely if I don't disconnect the screen.

This is really frustrating, and I don't understand why. I have re-installed screen several times (Debian-based system) and I have access to other servers where this problem don't exist when I move the code/data to them and process there. Unfortunately these servers are (technically) off limit so I can do the full processing there.

Any advice on how to proceed?

** UPDATE **

Here is some output after I disconnect the screen:

```
/edu/process/TOB.java:3: warning: PNGImageReaderSpi is internal   
proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
import com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReaderSpi;
                              ^
/edu/process/LPR.java:125: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
Dist<Double> d = new Dist("");
                             ^
required: Dist<Double>
found:    Dist
2 warnings
Error: Could not find or load main class edu.process.DService
```

The warning etc are ok and I have checked thoroughly that they do not interfere with the processing. It is the error. This is the main class that runs everything and after I disconnect the screen it just says it no longer exist.

Comment: How do you know that the framework is having problems? Do you see any output?

Comment: Never heard of such a problem. Can you include the specific error message?

Comment: after you opened new screen session, run "source ~/.bashrc", it will bring all your environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. Let me give you the "output" which happens after I disconnect the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after reinstalling.